# How to verify chained method calls?

Tags: mocking, mockito

I'm writing tests for my project's DAO class. But when I use Mockito's `verify()` method it throws `NullPointerException` because of `createQuery()` method returns `null`. How can I fix this?

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private EntityManager entityManagerMock;

@InjectMocks
private TaksitPlanSatiriDao taksitPlanSatiriDao = new TaksitPlanSatiriDaoJpa();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    taksitPlanSatiriEntity = new TaksitPlanSatiriEntity();
}
@Test
public void shouldUpdateWhenGuncelleCalledWithTaksitPlanSatiriEntity() {
    taksitPlanSatiriDao.guncelle(taksitPlanSatiriEntity);
    Mockito.verify(entityManagerMock).createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString()).executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Mockito.verify(entityManagerMock.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).executeUpdate();
```

This is based on the "Deep Stubs" documentation:

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS